# How do I count the number of items in each day for a month from the json data using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want write a program to calculate the sum of some variables for a single day for all the data present in json response from a mysql database with the help of ajax calls.

In this data, I want to access the

- date-time,
- CheckedCylinders,
- ProdRate

variables in such a way that the date 2021-05-30 the sum of cylinderchecked will be 9 and the prodRate will be the average of the prodrate and cylinderchecked.

For example

- Date 1 = 2021-05-31 =>  CyinderChecked = 1;
  (sum of all the cylinderchecked in one day)
- ProdRate= 1/1 = 1;
  (sum of prodrate in one day divided by cylinderchecked in one day.
- Date 2 = 2021-05-30 =>  CylinderChecked = 9;
  ( sum of all the cylinderchecked in one day)
- ProdRate= 6/9 = 0.67;
  (sum of prodrate in one day divided by cylinderchecked in one day.

```js
let data = [{
    "0": "2021-05-31 09:10:27",
    "1": "1",
    "2": "1",
    "Date": "2021-05-31 09:10:27",
    "ProdRate": "1",
    "CheckedCylinders": "1"
  },
  {
    "0": "2021-05-30 22:03:32",
    "1": "1",
    "2": "4",
    "Date": "2021-05-30 22:03:32",
    "ProdRate": "1",
    "CheckedCylinders": "4"
  },
  {
    "0": "2021-05-30 18:41:34",
    "1": "1",
    "2": "9",
    "Date": "2021-05-30 18:41:34",
    "ProdRate": "1",
    "CheckedCylinders": "9"
  },
  {
    "0": "2021-05-30 18:32:28",
    "1": "1",
    "2": "8",
    "Date": "2021-05-30 18:32:28",
    "ProdRate": "1",
    "CheckedCylinders": "8"
  },
  {
    "0": "2021-05-30 09:20:19",
    "1": "1",
    "2": "8",
    "Date": "2021-05-30 09:20:19",
    "ProdRate": "1",
    "CheckedCylinders": "8"
  }
]

function report(result, dates) {
  var totalCy = [],
    prodRate = [],
    sum1 = 0,
    sum2 = 0;

  for (let x in result) {
    totalCy.push(parseInt(result[x].CheckedCylinders));
    prodRate.push(parseInt(result[x].ProdRate));
  }
  for (x in totalCy && prodRate) {
    sum1 = sum1 + totalCy[x];
    sum2 = sum2 + prodRate[x];
  }

  sum2 = sum2 / sum1;
  for (var x in dates) {
    $(".degassingReportbody").append(`
        <tr>
        <td>${dates[x]}</td>
        <td>${sum1}</td>
        <td>${sum2}</td>
        </tr>
        `);
  }
}

function degassingReport(data) {
  //DATE & TIME Total Cyl Checked   Production Rate

  $(".degassingReportHead").append(`
        <tr>
        <th>DATE & TIME</th>
        <th>Total Cyl Checked</th>
        <th>Production Rate</th>
        </tr>
        `);
  let date = [];
  for (let x in data) {
    date.push(data[x].Date.split(" ")[0]);
  }
  let newDate = new Set(date);
  let dates = [...newDate];

  for (var x in dates) {
    result = data.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.Date.split(" ")[0] == dates[x];
    });
  }
  report(result, dates);
}

degassingReport(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead class="degassingReportHead"></thead>
  <tbody class="degassingReportbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your data is incorrect. You need unique IDs and commas between them. It seems you have an object array but your representation is not valid JSON/Object notation

Comment: Are you talking about the JSON data, Because I copied it from the chrome developer tool, allow me a minute to edit it

Comment: Yes please don’t use the developer tool version

Comment: your sample doesnt correspond to your json data

Comment: I have Edited the JSON data. @Frenchy my sample code gets the data from an ajax call.

Comment: hum for your second date how do you find 9 for cylinder, the sum is 4 +9 +8 +8?

Comment: I updated the snippet (we use snippets to show executable code) with relevant HTML

Comment: There are so many things not working, I cannot even do them all.
For example: `let dates = new Set(); data.forEach(({Date}) => dates.add(Date.split(" ")[0]));` why are you processing the dates over and over again?

Comment: Wy do you show the same sums on each line of the report?

Comment: This is likely not doing what you think it does `for (x in totalCy && prodRate) {` You cannot do a for in with two iterables in one statement

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for updating the snippet. Thanks for the help so far. Actually what I am doing is I'm going to through json data taking all the dates putting them in a new array which then I am iterating with that are with the the data and comparing it with something if they are then I am storing those data in a new result object calculating the cylinder check and product rate

Comment: @Frenchy previously I had 3 data in JSON element I added 2 more so now the calculation will be different according to the dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a solution using reduce:

```js
let data = [{
    "0": "2021-05-31 09:10:27",
    "1": "1",
    "2": "1",
    "Date": "2021-05-31 09:10:27",
    "ProdRate": "1",
    "CheckedCylinders": "1"
  },
  {
    "0": "2021-05-30 22:03:32",
    "1": "1",
    "2": "4",
    "Date": "2021-05-30 22:03:32",
    "ProdRate": "1",
    "CheckedCylinders": "4"
  },
  {
    "0": "2021-05-30 18:41:34",
    "1": "1",
    "2": "9",
    "Date": "2021-05-30 18:41:34",
    "ProdRate": "1",
    "CheckedCylinders": "9"
  },
  {
    "0": "2021-05-30 18:32:28",
    "1": "1",
    "2": "8",
    "Date": "2021-05-30 18:32:28",
    "ProdRate": "1",
    "CheckedCylinders": "8"
  },
  {
    "0": "2021-05-30 09:20:19",
    "1": "1",
    "2": "8",
    "Date": "2021-05-30 09:20:19",
    "ProdRate": "1",
    "CheckedCylinders": "8"
  }
]

var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
     let k = x[key].split(" ")[0];
     if(rv[k]){
      rv[k][0] += +x.ProdRate;
      rv[k][1] += +x.CheckedCylinders;
      rv[k][2] += rv[k][0]/rv[k][1]; 
     }else{
      rv[k] = [+x.ProdRate,+x.CheckedCylinders, (+x.ProdRate)/(+x.CheckedCylinders)];
     }
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
var groubedByDay=groupBy(data, 'Date');

degassingReport(groubedByDay);


function degassingReport(datas) {
  //DATE & TIME Total Cyl Checked   Production Rate

  $(".degassingReportHead").append(`
        <tr>
        <th>DATE & TIME</th>
        <th>Total Cyl Checked</th>
        <th>Production Rate</th>
        </tr>
        `);

  for (var x in datas) {
    $(".degassingReportbody").append(`
        <tr>
        <td>${x}</td>
        <td>${datas[x][1]}</td>
        <td>${datas[x][2]}</td>
        </tr>
        `);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead class="degassingReportHead"></thead>
  <tbody class="degassingReportbody"></tbody>
</table>
```